# How to concat strings from inputs with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I got 3 fields: name, last name and concat.

What I have to do is concat the first character of the field name with the last name.
And as I write, the field Concat is changing.

I have this by now:

```
<p>Name</p><input type="text" id="name"  onChange="document.getElementById('concat').value=this[0].value;" />
<p>Last name</p><input type="text" id="last_name" document.getElementById('txt').value=document.getElementById('txt').value + this.value;"/>
<p>Concat</p>
<input type="text" id="concat"  />
```

But the first character doesn't seem to be working, I think the problem might be in this[0].value; or how do I get the first chatacter, is there any other function to do it?.

Thanks, beforehand.

Comment: what does your javascript look like?

Comment: Is in the code above inside html input tags: onChange="document.getElementById('concat').value=this[0].value;"

Comment: thats not a very good pattern.

Comment: Might I suggest [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener) as a cleaner alternative to inline `on*` handlers?

Comment: Check this out. This might help you as well.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268245/find-the-first-character-of-input-in-a-textbox

Answer (score 0):

You're using `[0]` on `this` in your First-Name textbox, but it should be on the actual value instead:

```
onChange="document.getElementById('concat').value=this.value[0];"
```

Alternatively, you could be explicit and use `.substring()` to get the first character:

```
onChange="document.getElementById('concat').value=this.value.substring(0, 1);"
```

This will get the first character of the input. Though a bit longer to write/read, it will convey your exact purpose.

*Note:* If your input is empty, you will get an `undefined` value inserted into your `concat` textbox when you use `this.value[0]` as, well, there is no `[0]`. Using `.substring(0, 1)` will give no such text (if it's a concern).

Additionally, your second text-box for Last-Name has two typos (based on your sample code) in that it doesn't contain the `onchange=` attribute *and* it uses an id `txt` instead of `concat`. Also, it doesn't attempt to take a substring of the first-name textbox.

Try updating your full block of code to the following:

```
<p>Name</p>
<input type="text" id="name" onchange="document.getElementById('concat').value=this.value.substring(0, 1);" />
<p>Last name</p>
<input type="text" id="last_name" onchange="document.getElementById('concat').value=document.getElementById('name').value.substring(0, 1) + this.value;"/>
<p>Concat</p>
<input type="text" id="concat"  />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this[0].value
```

If you want the first character of the input fields value, that's not what you should do.

`this` is the input field. `this.value` is the string you want the first character of. And `this.value[0]` will get you that  strings first character.

So:

```
this.value[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You made some mistakes, here's your corrected code

```
<p>Name</p><input type="text" id="name"    onChange="document.getElementById('concat').value=this.value[0];" />
<p>Last name</p><input type="text" id="last_name" onChange="document.getElementById('concat').value=document.getElementById('name').value[0] + ' '    + this.value;"/>
<p>Concat</p>
<input type="text" id="concat"  />​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

please compare with your own code!